# Interface name as a Type

Tags: java, interface

I am trying to understand interfaces in Java and have this task to do which I am a stack with. It must be something easy, but I don't seem to see the solution. Interface contains a few methods, one of them should return true if all elements of this set are also in the set. I.e.

```
public interface ISet{
//some methods
   boolean isSubsetOf(ISet x);
}
```

Then the class:

```
public class myClass implements ISet{
       ArrayList<Integer> mySet;
       public myClass{
          mySet = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        }
       //some methods
       public boolean isSubsetOf(ISet x){
          //method body
    }
 }
```

What do I need to write in method body? How do I check that the instance of myClass is a subset of ISet collection? I was trying to cast, but it gives an error:

```
ArrayList<Integer> param = (ArrayList<Integer>)x;
    return param.containsAll(mySet);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interface is like an idea of a class.

It contains things like method definitions and static and final variables.

Therefore any class that implements them will contain a body (i.e. a way to handle that method in this class).

For eg.

```
public interface ISet{
    boolean isSubsetOf(ISet x);
}
```

Now any class that implements this will "handle" the method isSubsetOf and return a boolean. How they do this is not the interfaces business.
Now in your class

```
public class myClass implements ISet{
   ArrayList<Integer> mySet;
   public myClass(){
      mySet = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

   public boolean isSubsetOf(ISet x){
      //you now have to get what type of object x is
      // it is obviously implementing ISet therefore it most probably be myClass.
      //So when you typecast the object it should typecast to myClass.
      ArrayList<Integer> param = (ArrayList<Integer>)( ((myClass)x).mySet );
      return param.containsAll(mySet)
    }
}
```

This will work as we typecast x.mySet to ArrayList and x itself to myClass.

However there is a flaw in the logic. If you have another class implementing ISet then they might not typecast to myClass but in this case with on implements you will be fine.

It also seems like you are confused how to run this method so I'll add that

```
myClass A=new myClass();
A.add(1);    A.add(2);    A.add(3);
myClass B=new myClass();
B.add(3);    B.add(1);    B.add(2);   B.add(4);
A.isSubsetOf(B);
//This will answer true
```

Comment: No problem. I hope you understood the concept though

Answer (score 0):

> How do I check that the instance of myClass is a subset of ISet
>   collection

Use `instanceOf`:

`if(myClass instanceOf ISet){...}`

Answer (score 0):

An Interface is a class that defines the interface (function(s)  prototype(s)) that a concrete classed shares with other class.There cant be instance of a interface but of the concrete class for example `ISet iset = new myClass()` means u have created the instance of myClass(concrete) but variable of type ISet is holding reference.This is posible because of polymarphism. Because  `myClass` is providing definition of prototypes provide by `ISet`. With the help of polymorphism you can call only `iset.isSubsetOf(...)` because ISet has only one method prototype.

similarly witn the help of polymorphism you can do like that

```
ISet set1 = new myClass()
ISet set2 = new myClass()

set1.isSubsetOf(set2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The issue was in the ArrayList of Integers - I was trying to use containsAll() method, which is not really suitable. I used a loop to check if each element of subset can be found in the main set. And a separate find method, which would look for single element.

```
public boolean isSubsetOf(ISet x){
    myClass set = (myClass)x;
    boolean found = false;
    for (int element : mySet){
        found = false;
        if (set.find(element)){
            found = true;
        }
    }
    return found;
```

}